# Why does my array variable is not displaying in ng-repeat after being filled? (Angular Js)

Tags: angularjs, arrays, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

In my application, in the initialize, i have stated that

```
vm.allStates = [];
```

And then i trigger a function using ng-click, and update states based on country.

```
vm.allStates = result;
console.log(vm.allStates);
```

i get the desired output by doing so. My output is something like

```
["selangor"];
```

However in the HTML blade(as i am using Laravel 5.4), where i write

```
<option ng-repeat="option in vm.allStates" value="{{ option }}">@{{ option }}</option>
```

It does not output anything.
Meanwhile, if in the initialization, i stated that,

```
vm.allStates = ["selangor"];
```

It does display, however this becomes not dynamic.

I am wondering if this has something to do with ng-model? 
As it does not update the value, although, i can console.log the output.

I do not user ng-options, as i needed one selected value as placeholder,(in this case an option which is disabled and selected by default.

Thank you

EDIT 1:

```
storeService.storeByCountry(vm.countryId).then(function (response){
                vm.totalStores = response.length;

                if(response[0].country.has_zone){
                    vm.showZones = true;
                    vm.allZones = [...new Set(response.map(response => response.zone))];
                    vm.totalZones = vm.allZones.length;
                    vm.showFilterZones = true;
                }
                if(response[0].country.has_province){
                    vm.showProvinces = true;
                    vm.allProvinces = [...new Set(response.map(response => response.province))];
                    vm.totalProvinces = vm.allProvinces.length;
                    vm.showFilterProvinces = true;
                }
                if(response[0].country.has_state){
                    vm.showStates = true;
                    vm.allStates = [...new Set(response.map(response => response.state))];
                    vm.totalStates = vm.allStates.length;
                    vm.showFilterStates = true;
                }

                angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) {
                    addMarker({lat : +value.latitude, lng : +value.longitude}, vm.countryFilter);
                });
                console.log(vm.allStates);
                panToCountry(vm.countryFilter);
                return;
            }, function(error){
                APP.func.alerror(error);
            });
```

Comment: please post relevant code about where you are filling data into `vm.allStates`

Comment: There might be a problem with datastructure of result

Comment: is vm is ur scope variable?? are u missing scope here?? and 1 more thing did u initialize vm first $scope.vm={};

Comment: Yes i did. Nope, i dont think that is the issue.
@mastermind

Comment: Hm, which data structure do you mean?
@madhur

Comment: vm.allStates = result; in this line, make sure result is an array as you expect

Comment: yes, it is the result that i expect.
@madhur

Comment: make sure your js file has 'var vm = this;' and in html 'ng-controller="yourController as vm"'

Comment: i has that line.@the_mishra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After day of debugging, and thinking, it turns out that this issue is not caused by the angular not updating the array. It does , in fact.
The issue here, is the select style plugin that i used.

I used bootstrap-select for the looks of the select box, it turns out, that the value there is not updated, 
and so, when i remove this plugin, i can see the results i wanted.
Of course, there are workaround on this issue, however i decided not to look further on it

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code might be that you are using `vm.allState` in your `html`. You should not be doing that (unless `vm` is indeed the alias name). I believe `vm` referes to your controller instance (as it usually does). In that case you should be using any variable inside your controller using the controller alias in html.

Explanation:

If your controller has `vm.name = "Superman";`

This will be available in `html` as `ctrl.name` and not as `vm.name`. You might have named your alias differently and you should use the same alias.

Comment: No, i dont think so, i can print out vm.name if i declare it in controller, as i state xxController as vm, so there will be no problem on naming part

Comment: By printout, do you mean printing in console or screen ??